# LSCPU command: what is better in term of concurrency execution

Tags: linux, cpu

I have 2 Linux machines. I use `lscpu` command to check its CPU information.

Here is the first machine information:

```
CPU(s):                8
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-7
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             1
```

Here is the second machine information:

```
CPU(s):              6
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-5
Thread(s) per core:  1
Core(s) per socket:  1
Socket(s):           6
```

I have researched to see what are the differences between CPU, Core, Socket. For example [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364104/what-is-the-difference-between-cpu-and-core).  Based on that, I see that my second machine has more real processors, but in overall it has less than CPUs than the first one.

I want to ask in this situation, which machine is better in terms of concurrency execution? (I based only on total simultaneously threads, not on other factors such as speed/L1-L2 cache ...)